# Image not formatting correctly

Tags: html, css

Please can someone help me I am trying to get an image which is split into 6 equal parts to be centered in the page and at the size that I spliced the images into however its coming out all squashed and I cant work out what I am missing.

The images seem to be coming out square rather than rectangle which I believe is the issue but dont know what is doing that.

Appreciate any help! Thanks!

I have added the link but also been told to add the code
https://codepen.io/mikechristopher/pen/gMLEYx?editors=1100

HTML

```
<ul class="cards">
  <li class="cards__axis">
    <figure class="cards__front">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikechristopher/mikechristopher.github.io/master/images/0-0.jpeg" alt="" />

    </figure>
    <figure class="cards__back">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikechristopher/mikechristopher.github.io/master/images/0-0.jpeg" alt="" />
      <figcaption class="cards__description--back">
        <p>ABOUT</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="cards__axis">
    <figure class="cards__front">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikechristopher/mikechristopher.github.io/master/images/0-1.jpeg" alt="" />

    </figure>
    <figure class="cards__back">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikechristopher/mikechristopher.github.io/master/images/0-1.jpeg" alt="" />
      <figcaption class="cards__description--back">
        <p>PORTFOLIO</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="cards__axis">
    <figure class="cards__front">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikechristopher/mikechristopher.github.io/master/images/0-2.jpeg" alt="" />

    </figure>
    <figure class="cards__back">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikechristopher/mikechristopher.github.io/master/images/0-2.jpeg" alt="" />
      <figcaption class="cards__description--back">
        <p>CONTACT</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="cards">
  <li class="cards__axis">
    <figure class="cards__front">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikechristopher/mikechristopher.github.io/master/images/1-0.jpeg" alt="" />

    </figure>
    <figure class="cards__back">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikechristopher/mikechristopher.github.io/master/images/1-0.jpeg" alt="" />
      <figcaption class="cards__description--back">
        <p>LINK</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="cards__axis">
    <figure class="cards__front">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikechristopher/mikechristopher.github.io/master/images/1-1.jpeg" alt="" />

    </figure>
    <figure class="cards__back">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikechristopher/mikechristopher.github.io/master/images/1-1.jpeg" alt="" />
      <figcaption class="cards__description--back">
        <p>LINK</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="cards__axis">
    <figure class="cards__front">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikechristopher/mikechristopher.github.io/master/images/1-2.jpeg" alt="" />

    </figure>
    <figure class="cards__back">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikechristopher/mikechristopher.github.io/master/images/1-2.jpeg" alt="" />
      <figcaption class="cards__description--back">
        <p>LINK</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>


<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('.cards__back').hide();
  $('.cards__axis').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find('.cards__back').fadeToggle();
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('.cards__back').fadeToggle();
  });
})();
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

CSS

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
}

.cards * {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cards__axis {
  position: relative;
}

.cards__axis:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.cards__front,
.cards__back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.9s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.9s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.9s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.9s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.9s ease-in-out;
}

.cards__front {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
}

.cards__axis:hover .cards__front {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(-180deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.cards__back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(180deg);
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(180deg);
}

.cards__axis:hover .cards__back {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0);
  -moz-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0);
  -ms-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0);
  -o-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0);
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0);
}


/* CUSTOM STYLES FOR THIS UNORDERED LIST */

.cards {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 15%;
}

.cards {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: none;
}

.cards:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.cards__axis {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.cards__description--back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 98%;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.cards__description--back p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'Impact', sans-serif;
  color: #880000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of the aspect ratio. You set the height of the panels to 100% but that's unrelated to the width so the ratio is not being maintained. To see what  I mean, remove the `height:100%` from one of the `.cards__back` image panels and it comes out "not squished".

Remember that `height` comes from the width of the parent element.

So how do you maintain that aspect ratio? There are a number of ways that I don't have time to go into, and would require editing your markup, but you can set the height of a panel to zero and then the padding-bottom to some percent of the height until you get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me - I understand your point on the height and did have it omitted originally however then I am left with whitespace between the top and bottom section and cant figure out how to pull them in together. it worked ok when I was using images of a different size and square but it just doesnt like these rectangular images :)